# subjunctive after "would like"

Tags: verbs

Which sentence is grammatically correct ?

- I would like that we try together
- I would like that we tried together

Should the subordinate clause use the subjunctive present ? I know that it is used for both present and past events, but I am not sure about the conditional. If so, I guess the first sentence is the correct one.

note: I know that "I would like us to try together" is more usual.

Comment: I would like to try together!

Comment: I don't find either of those at all natural: they sound to me like a typical thing that a non-native speaker would say, translating from the structure in their own language.